# Number increment algorithm efficiency

Tags: algorithm

I'm stuck on optimising an algorithm; the algorithm works as such. Say we have an expression `a+b+c+d` and the algorithm was to attain every combination of numbers possible up to a number; let's say, `n= 10`.
So the algorithm would be outputting this;

```
1+1+1+1
1+1+1+2
1+1+1+3
..............
1+1+1+10
1+1+2+1
```

And so on, until it reaches the end which would be

```
10+10+10+10
```

However the problem I'm having is the runtime of the algorithm increases rapidly as `n`(max number) increases.

Are there any ways of cutting the runtime when `n` increases. I'm seriously stumped.

Can't post source code ATM as I'm not at home, but it was done in c++.

Comment: if you need every possible variation, that'll blow up combinatorially, no matter what. You can reduce the constant factors (by using symmetries of variations and the fact that addition is commutative), but that won't help either after a certain point.

Comment: The algorithm runs in exponential time in terms of the n.  A NP problem.

Comment: If you need to produce n^4 results, the best you can do is an O(n^4) algorithm. Luckily, this is precisely the complexity of the naïve algorithm.

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa: This is nonsense. The problem isn't even a decision problem, so it is completely unrelated to NP.

Comment: @tropicalmemes NP means nondeterministic polynomial time. [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the combination part, if "a+b+c+d" equals "a+b+d+c", then you can save some time by write the loop as

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j < n; ++j {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

but O(n^4) is needed.

Otherwise, if the problem is exactly "attain every combination of numbers possible up to a number", there should be a closed form solution from 4 to 4*n.

you don't need to attain every combination. just calc the result. Or I misunderstanding the question.

Comment: save the intermediate result maybe helpful. 
For example, you don't need to calc "1+1" many times.

Comment: Saving results so I don't have to repeat the same numbers. This is exactly the stuff I need. Because  in my source code I have to build my expression from the ground up I.e "a; a+;a+b;a+b+c;" etc. thanks